# Exception log file not generating after I upgraded my Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.6

Tags: magento-upgrade, log, magento2.4.6

After upgrading from magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.6, exception log file is not generating. How do I fix this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This will work with the newest Magento 2.4.3+. it is tested on Magento 2.4.6 version.

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```